# Golang PDF (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: api, pdf, go

Tengo un problema al generar un *PDF* con `golang` usando la **lib. wkhtmltopdf**,
el código corre y crea el *PDF*, pero al abrirlo me causa error ó está totalmente en blanco.

Si alguien ha trabajado con otra librería y me puede decir cuál, sería de mucha ayuda.

Aquí el codigo:

```
pdf.SetPath("./vistas")

file, err := pdf.NewPDFGenerator()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

file.Dpi.Set(300)
file.Orientation.Set(pdf.OrientationPortrait)
file.Grayscale.Set(true)

page := pdf.NewPage("http://localhost:8080/")
page.FooterRight.Set("[page]")

file.AddPage(page)

err = file.Create()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

err = file.WriteFile("./estado.pdf")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

Comment: intenta ejecutar el comando de `wkhtmltopdf` con el html que te genera esto te dara un error, agregala a la respuesta y con ello te podemos ayudar

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto por consola si crea bien el pdf, pero por codigo no, creo que trabajare de otra manera para utilizar el script por separado

Comment: Me parece que esta es la librería que estás usando: https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Si, es esa librería, no se si configure algo mal pero no genera bien el pdf. me gustaria darles mas detalles pero no me arroja ningún error.

Comment: Deberias hacer un issue report en la libreria directamente. Tu codigo no es reproducible con la seccion limitada que pusiste en la pregunta.